# How to avoid duplicate files and text in a NodeJs application?

Tags: node.js, md5, cryptojs

**I have the following use case -**
1. Avoid duplicate files
2. Avoid duplicate text code

I understand I need to calculate both the files and text codes into MD5 and maintain both into columns,
which can be queried, to check if the same file or text code might already be there in the application.

I am trying to find the correct way to create MD5 Checksums in NodeJs,
**I found the following to be useful -**

```
let crypto = require('crypto');
let md5CheckSum = crypto.createHash('md5').update(dataToConvert).digest("hex");
```

**I have the following queries -**

1. Is calculating MD5 and MD5 Checksum the same thing?
2. Is the code creating just an MD5, or is it also creating the checksum of the `dataToConvert` string?
   if not how can I further create its checksum?
3. It is straightforward to pass text codes to the md5 function,
   In case of files, what conversion do I need to do?
   To be passed as an argument to the md5 checksum function?

**Reference -**
https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm_options

Answer (score 0):

1. yes
2. there is no such thing as "an md5", md5 checksums are cryptographic hashes *of some data*, so in this case that data is `dataToConvert`. No data, no md5.
3. you're in Node, have a look at [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)

Comment: if my file will be an image, what do I have to pass to the update method?

Comment: That's what you read the docs for. https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_update_data_inputencoding